# Touching animation in RecyclerView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

In my item of list xml I set this code:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

It will make some ripple animations when I pressed on RecyclerView item.
To get item click I used this class:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
}
```

and use it like this example:

```
rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Log.d("OnClick", "click at " + position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailEventActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("EVENT", list.get(position - 1));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }));
```

This is my layout with RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is layout of my item layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/text_color"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/event_card_icon"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add 500 rub"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            app:typeface="roboto_light"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
            android:id="@+id/event_description"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ic_replay"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/time_of_publish"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:textColor="#b8b8b8"
            app:typeface="roboto_regular"
            android:layout_below="@id/event_description"/>

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+4"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:typeface="roboto_regular"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_points_small"
            android:textColor="#cccccc"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/time_of_publish"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ic_replay"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/event_description"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/time_of_publish"
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#ebebeb"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I saw many questions and answers, and I don't know why this code doesn't work. Maybe somebody can help me.

**My problem** is to press animation on RecyclerView item doesn't work for me.

Comment: does your log Log.d("OnClick", "click at " + position); contain the position of clicked item?

Comment: your problem is that the ripple animation is not working?

Answer (score 0):

create a ripple drawable inside your drawable-v21 folder, id mask is to limit the ripple effect inside the bounds of the row you clicked :
ripple_drawable.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:color="your rippleeffect color">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask"
     android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

inside your item layout's Relative layout change the android:background attribute to

```
android:background="@drawable/ripple_drawable"
```

Comment: wow...did really nobody answer your issue then? Did you manage to find a solution to this?